# .htaccess mobile redirect only main page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mobile

I need short help on mobile redirect with some rules, here is what i have as rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "iphone|ipad|ipod|android|nokia|ios|opera m(ob|in)i|iemobile|symbian|samsung|htc|huawei|sonyericsson|blackberry|motorola|lenovo|lg|mot|alcatel|asus-|googlebot-mobile|psp|dalvik|windows ce|webos" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http:\/\/(www\.)?example.com\/(index.php)?$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ http://example.com/mobile/ [R]
```

How to edit it so it would work: once you go to **example.com** without any page name or subfolder, it would be redirected (if one of mobile browsers) to **example.com/mobile/** But once user is going to **example.com/some/** or **example.com/page.php** he won't get redirected.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(/)?$` only impacts `example.com` request but won't route `example.com/some/` requests.

Comment: i don't need to readdress "example.com/some/" only example.com if mobile should be redirected

Comment: Right and your current rule is only rewriting `example.com/` at present.

Comment: Yes, u right, is there a way to fix it without dublicating rule?

Comment: Sorry I'm confused on what needs to be fixed as your rule is already doing what you need.